# react native image contain empty space

Tags: android, ios, image, react-native

In react native, I render image like below code:

```
<Image
    source={{
      uri: downloadDest,
      scale: 1
    }}
      style={styles.image}
      resizeMode='contain'
  >
</Image>

image: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: 'blue',
},
```

this code render like below images, in this situation I need to calc empty padding between image and parent view.

how can I calc W, H, image height and image width?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

- resizeMode is a Style prop.
- If you wanna prioritize filling the gaps over quality of the image, try resizeMode: 'stretch' or 'cover'.

This should work:

```
<Image
    source={{
      uri: downloadDest,
      scale: 1
    }}
      style={styles.image}
  >
</Image>

image: {
   flex: 1,
   resizeMode: 'cover', //or stretch/contain
   backgroundColor: 'blue',
},
```

Comment: I need to render an image with correct aspect ratio but when use stretch or cover image aspect ratio becomes wrong

Comment: cover doesn't change aspect ratio, but parts of your image wont appear in your "View"